# Stylus ParseError: expected “indent”, got “;”

Tags: css, gruntjs, stylus

Screenshot:
http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=424e87f390411d3932bb3d73ff613e58

Part of the file "Gruntfile.js"

```
sprite: {
      mixins: {
        src: ['layout/media/images/sprite/*.png'],
        destImg: 'layout/media/images/sprite.png',
        destCSS: 'layout/assets/css/variables/sprite-mixins.styl',
        algorithm: 'binary-tree',
        padding: 1,
        imgPath: '../images/sprite.png',
        cssTemplate: 'sprite_template/mixins.mustache',
        cssVarMap: function (sprite) {
          sprite.name = 's-' + sprite.name;
        },
      },
    },
```

Everything worked perfectly in the several projects. Suddenly, there was a mistake.

Using grunt and plugin - grunt-spritesmith.

(https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith).

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can't start a mixin with a dot in Stylus. If you remove `.` from `.s-demo();` call, all will be fine.

Comment: Panya, thank you very much!

I did it: 
`.classname {
  margin: .....;

  s-demo();
}`

No `.`

Now, well:)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but there was no identifyable character and the error kept moving lines whenever I would delete one.

Turns out, I had mixed spaces and tabs in the document.

Converting all to spaces in Sublime Text fixed it for me.